# How can I connect to S3 APS External Download?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to access `s3://aps-external-download` using .NET SDK

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var response = await client.ListObjectsAsync();

foreach (var x in response.S3Objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", x.BucketName);
}
```

But I'm getting `Access Denied`

```
{Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception}
ErrorCode: AccessDenied
ErrorMessage: Access Denied
```

From `aws` CLI, I'm able to list the folders

```
aws s3 ls s3://aps-external-download/***/
PRE ***_report/
PRE ***_report/
```

I'm trying to find a solution from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/index.html documentation but it's not been helpful.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Are you using the same IAM user's credentials in CLI and your code? Make sure that the one in your code has the correct permissions to access the bucket.

Comment: I believe I am...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using the wrong method.

```
var response = await client.GetObjectAsync("aps-external-download/path/to/the/report/1999-01-01", "report_file");

var reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream);

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```